# Why doesn't my code work when I use a while loop?

Tags: java

Tonight I was working on problem 1 from http://projecteuler.net/problem=1.  It is not working using the while loop.  I did get it to work using two short cut if statements.  After correctly solving it I see on the forum there are better solutions using math, but I am new and need to learn what went wrong with my while loop.

Here is the question:
If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.  Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.  Correct answer = 233168

```
    public class Project1_Multiples_of_3_and_5 {
//Main method
public static void main (String args[])
{   
    int iResult = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000 / 3; i++)  // for all values of i less than 333 (1000 / 3)
    {
        iResult += i * 3;  // add i*3 to iResults
        //the short cut if below works but I want to use a while loop
                //iResult +=  (i % 3 !=0 && i < 1000 / 5) ? i * 5 : 0;  // add i*5 to iResults excluding the multiples 3 added in the previous step while i < 200 ( 1000 / 5 )

        while ( (i < 1000 / 5) && (i % 3 != 0) )
        {
            iResult += i * 5;
/************************************************************************************
SOLVED!!! ... sort of
adding a break makes the code work but defeats the purpose of using a loop.  I guess     I    should just stick with my 2 if statements
************************************************************************************/

                        break;
        }//end while
    }// end for

    System.out.println(iResult);

    }//end main method
}//end class
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: are you updating i... it doesn't look like it.  You need to update i inside the while loop or it will never exit the while

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `while` loop never terminates, since you never change the variable (`i`) in the end condition:

```
while ( (i < 1000 / 5) && (i % 3 != 0) )
{
    iResult += i * 5; // i is not updated here
}//end while
```

Also, the second condition will cause the loop to exit as soon as a multiple of 3 is encountered, which is probably not what you want.
One idea could be to change this to a `for` loop like the one you have for the multiples of 3 (and move it out of the first `for` loop).

Comment: You're still not updating `i` in each `while` loop body.

Comment: @oconnor0: No, I just quoted the code. Added a comment in the relevant place.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: Thanks everybody that clears it up.  It looks like it does not make much sense for me to try and use a for loop there.